# Reading a file and performing functions based on the contents of the line

Tags: java, file, if-statement, numbers, line

I'm wondering if it's possible to read a file by the line number, each with different values and make a condition where if that line contains a certain string or number specified. If it did it would, for example, take the content specified in that line into a variable?

So in a file line one has Age: 50, line 2 has Age: 23, line 3 has Age: 34. What I'm hoping for is that I look specifically at line 3 and take the number 34 and place it in a variable for use in my program.

If it is possible, how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, it is not possible to directly address a specific line unless - perhaps you know the line sizes of your file, etc... to seek through the file. But you can use this to go through your file, line by line:

```
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // do some cool stuff with this line.
}
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Reading a file and performing functions based on the contents of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245950/reading-a-file-and-performing-functions-based-on-the-contents-of-the-line)

You can always iterate through each line, keeping track of the line via an int or a short.

some code:

```
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_HERE));
int line = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   line++;
   if(line == 3){
       //do whatever you want
   }
}
br.close();
```

I will add that getting something from one single line while others also have identical info is bad

Comment: Improve the answer please, this could have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the scanner object to read through a file.  you would use the delimiter to find the info you want and a counter to keep track of the line, then put it in an arraylist or something.  depending on what you want to do.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(filename);
int line = 0;
in.useDelimiter("[regex of the info you are looking for]");
while in.hasNext()) {
  line++
  //do something
}
```